# How do I round to 3d.p in mysql

Tags: mysql

In MySql I have a column called price. I want to update the figures in price by rounding each price to 3 decimal places. What is the correct mysql function to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with  [Format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

```
  Select Format (price ,3) from TableName ;
```

Comment: That does it but I want it to update the column with the prices. So I tried update format (price ,3) from Table1 ; but this didnt work

Comment: can u edit your post with existing table desc and with values?How you tried ? what you are expecting ? @userH

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this:-

```
 SELECT FORMAT(12324.2573, 3);
```

or

```
SELECT FORMAT(price, 3);
```

or

```
select round(price,3)
```

Comment: select price from table1 Format(price,3) - this does not work

Comment: You can try this as I have posted in my answer also :- Select Format (price ,3) from TableName ;